# Doing an update instantly after read

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

Suppose I have multiple instances of an app reading a single row with a query like the following

```
r.db('main').
table('Proxy').
filter(r.row('Country').eq('es').and(r.row('Reserved').eq(false))).
min(r.row('LastRequestTimeMS'))
```

the `'Reserved'` field is a bool
I want to guarantee that the same instance that have read that value do an update to set the `'Reserved'` value to `true` to prevent other instances from reading it

can someone please point me to how I can make this guarantee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the way you want to do something like this is you want to issue a conditional `update` instead, and look at the returned changes to get the read.  Something like `document.update(function(row) { return r.branch(row('Reserved'), r.error('reserved'), {Reserved: true}); }, {returnChanges: true})`.